# Understanding jQuery Ajax Function: Call Code-behind C# Method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I need some help with JavaScript as I'm a novice and I can't get the jquery ajax to call my method in code behind. I'm trying to adapt this example to my needs, but I'm not getting the expected results. [Understand jQuery Ajax Function: Call Code-behind C# Method](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-jquery-ajax-function-call-code-behind-C-Sharp-method/)

1. I cannot determine whether button "BtnAgain" is actually calling the script.
2. If the button is in fact calling the script, It seems like the url in the ajax is not finding the method in the code behind.

Here is my code:

JavaScript.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="JavaScript.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication.JavaScript" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head runat="server">  
    <title></title>  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
         <script>  
             $(document).ready(function SaveImage() {
                 
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "JavaScript.aspx/GetData",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function (response) {
                         $("#Content").text(response.d);
                         alert('Function called successfully !');
                     },
                     failure: function (response) {
                         alert(response.d);                         
                     }
                 });
             });
         </script> 
</head>  
    
<body>  
    <form id="frm" runat="server">
    <div id="Content">  
    </div>  
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click1" Text="ASP Button" />
        <asp:Button ID="BtnAgain" runat="server" OnClientClick="SaveImage()" Text="JS Button" />          

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript.aspx.cs

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
namespace WebApplication
{
    public partial class JavaScript : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetData()
        {            
            return "This string is from Code behind";
        }

        protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = GetData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? If you have an `onclick="SaveImage()"`, then this function is [out of scope](/q/1055767/4642212). The function `SaveImage` is already being called as soon as the page loads. Does the call at least work? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and look into the Network tab. Do you see the request there? Is it successful, i.e. a 200 status? Click on it and look into the Response tab. Do you see the string “This string is from Code behind” in the response?

Comment: Thanks for the input. The button executes the desired method it seems like but the method result is 401 with the following error. {Message: "Authentication failed.", StackTrace: null,…}
ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"
Message: "Authentication failed."
StackTrace: null